# is UIScrollView reuseable? in swift

Tags: ios, swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlWOY.gif)

when I was developing horizon container ScrollView, my custom indicator's frame is changed after scrolling other scrollView. I don't know why.

why UIScrollView's indicator is changed frame after scrolling other ScrollView? I wrote just code that is some lines in **`scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)`**

```
funt scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView === firstScrollView {
     // firstScrollView hava a indicator 
     // this area is empty... 
   } else if scrollView === secondScrollView {
     // secondScrollView didn't hava a indicator
       firstScrollView.contentOffset.x = scrollView.contentOffset.x 
   }
}
```

anyone give me a why is scrollView's indicator reuseable..?

current view's overall hierarchy is

```
| ContainerVC
|-- ScrollView(vertical)
|---- HeaderView
|---- firstScrollView(horizon)
|------ indicator
|---- secondScrollView(horizon)
```

firstScrollView and secondScrollView are not connected with each other in code, that is weird. so I have tried temporally this work in storyBoard and I have seen same conditions.. where is wrong?

Comment: Can you explain how is indicator linked with the firstViewController? When you scroll the secondScrollView, you change the firstScrollView's offset in scrollViewDidScroll method. I guess the indicator is changing because it is connected somehow with the firstScrollView.

Comment: @AlexNazarov thank you for your comments. I have written addition explanation. if you think to be short my opinion. please, don't hesitate to tell me